# SQL query to find a record which has all matching records in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below 3 tables  and I want to write a SQL query which will list the store present in all city: (here the result should be "Walmart")

```
Stores:
ID  Name
1   Walmart
2   Target
3   Sears

Stores_City
ID  Store_id     City ID
1   1            10
2   1            20
3   2            10
4   1            30


City
ID  Name
10  NewYork
20  Boston
30  Eagan
```

I am unable to find a query that works. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.Name
from Stores s 
inner join
(
select store_id, count(distinct city_id)
from stores_city
group by store_id
having count(distinct city_id) = (select count(*) from City)
) x
on x.store_id = s.id;
```

You can do it by grouping on store_id and checking for the count from stores table.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I just wanted to ask if in the inner query you meant (select (count(*) from city) so the query would look like   select s.Name
from Stores s 
inner join
(
select store_id, count(distinct city_id)
from stores_city
group by store_id
having count(distinct city_id) = (select count(*) from city)
) x
on x.store_id = s.id;

Answer (score 0):

A straight join would work

Select distinct s.name from stores s inner join store _city SC on s.id=sc.id
Inner join city c on
Sc.city_id = c.id

Comment: I think straight join would get me back all the stores which are present in one or more city. Whereas I am looking for the store which is present in all city.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that will work:

```
select s.*
from stores s
where not exists (
  select c.id
  from city c
  except
  select sc.city_id
  from stores_city sc
  where sc.store_id = s.id
)
```

Comment: I didn't understand how this will work but the previous answer from Sagar did help. Thanks though!

Comment: @user5252179: If you are going with his answer, don't forget to mark his answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark next to his posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    s.Name
FROM Stores s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1
    1
FROM City c
LEFT JOIN Stores_City sc
    ON c.ID = sc.CityID
    AND sc.Store_id = s.ID
WHERE sc.ID IS NULL)
```